# Refresh Table Adapter affects cell focus

Tags: c#, datagridview, focus, tableadapter

I'm using the following code to commit cell changes to the database and calculate the value of another cell in the database. While I realize it isn't the norm to store a calculated value, I haven't been able to find a way to calculate the cell at the database level.

```
    private void dgvPlayers_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            this.Validate();
    .
    .   
    .
            playerListBindingSource.EndEdit();
            playerListTableAdapter.UpdatePlayerAvg(Convert.ToDecimal(average), Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPlayers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value));
            playerListTableAdapter.Update(dsPlayerTeam.PlayerList);
            this.playerListTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsPlayerTeam.PlayerList);
        }
    }
```

The problem I've run into is that **TableAdapter.Fill** method causes unexpected changes to the cell focus. If I'm tabbing through the fields, everything works as expected, however if I use the cursor keys to change rows, then the focus will shift to a different column, usually (but not always) the first column.

I thought I could store the row and column indexes of the current cell and key pressed in a **keydown** event then manually set the focus at the end of my **CellValidated** handler. What I found was that the **keydown** event I attached to the **DataGridView** was never called probably because the **DataGridView** is actually a collection of controls. This was what I tried:

```
dgvPlayers.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(dgvPlayers_KeyDown);
.
.
.

private void dgvPlayers_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView theGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    dgvPlayersKeyPress = e.KeyCode;
}
```

Since I was never able to collect the Key press, I was never able to manually set the focus.

Are there any other options here? Perhaps there's a way to refresh the bound data for a specific cell rather than .Fill for the whole tableadapter?

I still haven't found a suitable solution to this problem. Does anyone have a recommendation? What I've come to understand is that the cell that when it performs the .Fill, it clears the table, then regenerates the rows which explains the strange focus behaviour. I'm starting to think that I should unbind the datagridview, and manually read and write data to the database. I would really prefer to avoid this.

ThanX!

Comment: Still no ideas? I've run the course on trying to collect the key press with no luck and I can't find a reason for the cursor position to be lost when the **tableadapter** refreshes.